# How to add the sum of a column to the same SQL query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sum

I have a table looking like this:

```
ID, Weight
_____________
number, Value
```

Now I want to add another column with the sum of all weights in every row to a query. Like this:

```
ID, weight, sumOfWeight
_____________________________
number, value, sum of values
```

with the sql code being:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.weight, sum(t.weight) as sumOfW
FROM Table t
```

Is there a way to do this in Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select that dynamically

```
select ID, 
       weight,
       (select sum(weight) from your_table) as sumOfWeight
from your_table
```